# Django Admin: Creating users in the browser

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have setup my Django (1.8) admin to allow superusers to create new users interactively. My User model is customized using `AbstractUser` which means my admin file looks like this:

*admin.py*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import CPRUser

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    model = CPRUser
    extra = 1

admin.site.register(CPRUser, UserAdmin)
```

and here is the model:

```
class CPRUser(AbstractUser):
    student = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=_("student"),
                                            default=0,
                                            blank=True)
    saved = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This appears to work OK, I can go through the admin and set the password, username and all the other custom fields of a new user. However, when I try and login with the newly created user, some part of the authentication process fails. I login from a page which is using the `auth_views.login` view and the boilerplate django login template.

On the other hand, if I create a new user using either `manage.py createsuperuser` or `createuser()` within the django shell, these users can login fine. This leads me to suspect it is to do with password storage or hashing - currently in the admin I can just type in a new user's password. Thing is, that is what I want to be able to do. How can I get this desired result - I want non-IT savy managers (whose details I won't have) to be able to easily create new users in the admin. I am aware of the risks of such a system.

The docs seem contradictory on [setting this interactive user creation up](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#managing-users-in-the-admin) in one section:

"The “Add user” admin page is different than standard admin pages in that it requires you to choose a username and password before allowing you to edit the rest of the user’s fields."

and then a couple of paragraphs later:

"User passwords are not displayed in the admin (nor stored in the database)"

Here is a screen shot of my admin:

[image]

How can I make Django accept the login attempts of users created interactively via the admin?

Comment: Can you give more details on authentication failure? I.e. what the exact exception and the message is?

Comment: @BasicWolf that's part of the problem - what's the easiest way to dig into the authentication failure? None of my code is doing the authentication - it's all the django auth black box.

Comment: -- However, when I try and login with the newly created user, some part of the authentication process fails. -- so, how exactly you try to login the newly-created user?

Comment: Sorry, have updated the question to make it clearer. I'm using the `auth_views.login` view and the boilerplate django login template.

Comment: First make sure that the users and passwords are actually stored in the database. Verify, that the stored passwords are hashes, not the raw ones. Next, perform a test in a django shell: `from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm`; `AuthenticationForm(data={'username': 'USER_NAME_HERE', 'password': 'RAW_PASSWORD_HERE'}).is_valid()` - this should evaluate to `True`. As a last resort - simply debug into `login()`'s code via IDE or pudb.

Comment: The users and passwords are definitely stored in the database, but the stored passwords are not hashes. The `is_valid()` check returns false

Comment: Have you tried using `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin` as a base class for admin?

Comment: That was the problem - please add it as an answer so I can accept, and thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin),

> If your custom User model extends django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser, you can use Django’s existing django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin class.

So, extending `UserAdmin` should do the trick.