# Cant login to created user after using custom model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,User
from django.utils.html import escape,mark_safe
# Create your models here.
class user(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def login_view(request):
form = AuthenticationForm()
if request.method=='POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username,password=password)
    if user.is_admin==True:
        login(request,user)
        return HttpResponse(f"Welcome {username}")
    else:
        return HttpResponse('failled')

return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

cant login using the user created by superuser.
the user is creating but while calling it or using it shows

[created a user with staff and superuser authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUSxU.png)
[still cant login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjo4i.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Also, not sure why you're overriding the login view. You can use another setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to set the URL where the user gets redirected on successful login.

Comment: actually i am new to django

Comment: i added the `AUTH_USER_MODEL='users.user'` in **settings.py**

Comment: i am overriding the view cz i want to see different landing page based on roles

Comment: Also, I think that you made a mistake when instantiating the AuthenticationForm. It looks like there are no data from the request passed to it. Try `AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)`.

Comment: Regarding the different landing page according to roles, I think having a separate RedirectView would be a better idea. I would not change the authentication view if I absolutely don't have to. It can create vulnerabilities.

Comment: its same problem i think the problem occur because of the custom model

Comment: can you check my model i think something is wrong there

Comment: In your model, admin is something different than Django superuser?

Comment: no i just created class user to create different roles and after using that user as `admin.site.register('user')` now if I create any user by superuser and even I give superuser authorization to that  newly created user I cant login using that in admin panel

Comment: i include the **User class** above

Comment: Are you sure the credentials get picked up from the frontend correctly? It does not seem to me that the Model is the issue. Any logs from the error in the console?

Comment: After using `admin.site.register('user')` if i somewhere calls the newly created user like `if user.is_admin==True:` it showing me **NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_admin'**

Comment: as i am using MYSQL as database I can see the user is created and its `is_admin` value is 1

Comment: It looks like the line with `user = authenticate(...)` fails. It seems to me that username/password don't arrive properly in the form data. How does your form look like (HTML)?

Comment: I think form is ok cz when i use same login interface for my superuser login it shows the **Welcome admin** message the problem occurs if i create any new user from admin panel

Comment: So you set is_staff and is_superuser. What about is_active?

Comment: I only created the roles mentioned above didn't do anything further

Comment: Can you add the code where you register your UserAdmin?

Comment: i added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.user'` to **settings.py**  and `admin.site.register(user)` at **admin.py** nothing else

Comment: This might be the problem, I think the answer above is correct. See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786387/django-admin-creating-users-in-the-browser

Answer (score 0):

You need to unregister the built-in User from the admin and then register your own user model in `admin.py`

[Example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from customauth.models import user


admin.site.register(user, UserAdmin)
# admin.site.unregister(User)
```

You may have to subclass the UserChangeForm to add your custom fields

Comment: Do i need to make migration after that?

Comment: @PrantaNathNayan no you don't, this only affects the admin, no model changes

Comment: it shows _raise NotRegistered('The model %s is not registered' % model.__name__)
django.contrib.admin.sites.NotRegistered: The model User is not registered_ after adding your given code

Comment: Make sure your app comes after `django.contrib.auth` in your INSTALLED_APPS setting, or you may be able to remove that line

Comment: i moved the app in the last line still showing same notRegister error

Comment: @PrantaNathNayan remove the line then

Comment: now its saying _AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.user' that has not been installed_

Comment: Did you remove the app from INSTALLED_APPS? I meant remove the unregister line in admin.py if you did

Comment: @lainShelvington after removing `admin.site.unregister(User)` its working but my custom made roles are vanished its only showing the built in roles