# How to give access to different object of a model to different users in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am doing an online classroom project in Django where I created a model named course which is accessible by teachers. **Now I am trying to add students/users in a particular course by inviting students or students can enroll using "clasroom_id"(a unique field I used in the model) just like we invite people in google classroom to join classes. How to do that?**
I added the models and views of the course object below.

*models.py*

```
class course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course_sec = models.IntegerField()
    classroom_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_name

    def is_valid(self):
        pass
```

*views.py*

```
def teacher_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = add_course(request.POST or None)
    context = {}
    if form.is_valid():
        course = form.save(commit=False)
        course.created_by = request.user
        course.save()
        return HttpResponse("Class Created Sucessfully")
    context['add_courses'] = form
    return render(request, 'teacherview.html', context)

def view_courses(request, *args, **kwargs):
    students = course.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
    dict = {'course':students}
    return render(request, 'teacherhome.html',dict)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please outline the question you are specifically asking. Also add what you have attempted.

Comment: I am trying to add students/users in a particular course by inviting students or students can enroll using "clasroom_id"(a unique field I used in the model) how to do that? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I have edited the post please tell me  can you understand my question now? @DougM

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE** This answer is just a general idea of an approach.

What you want here is a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) between your Student/User model and the course model, since supposedly many students can have a Course, and a Course can have Many Students.  You could do this with your user model, but it'll be easier for me to answer with a separate Student model connected to the user model, such as:

```py
from django.conf import settings

class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is one way to separate different types of users, for example, teachers from students, by [extending the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) with a OneToOneField.  You could also just add another field to your user model, such as user_type, if you have a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) already in place.

Now to your actual question.  Set up the ManyToManyField (Note how I capitalize class names (Course, not course):

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course_sec = models.IntegerField()
    classroom_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, blank=True)
```

Now the simple part.  When you want to add a student to the course, all you have to do is first get the course by querying for the classroom_id, then adding the student to it:

```py
student = Student.objects.get(student=request.user)
course = Course.objects.get(classroom_id=request.POST.get('classroom_id'))
course.add(student)
```

Note that the add() function automatically saves.  The ManyToManyField will create an intermediate table between Students and Courses.  Read up on the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) to see how you can query to get all students in a course, or to get all courses a student has.

**Edit**
If you are going to use your User model instead of creating a seperate Student and Teacher model, like I believe you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71301221/cant-login-to-created-user-after-using-custom-model), that is fine.  You can just change the ManyToManyField like this:

```py
# Instead of:
class Course(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    course_sec = models.IntegerField()
    classroom_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
```

Then in your view,

```py
Course.objects.get(classroom_id=request.POST.get('classroom_id'))
course.add(request.user)
```

Comment: I am a beginner at Django can you please explain if I use  "group" to separate teachers from students what should be my approach? @raphael

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "group", @PrantaNathNayan, but I've updated my answer in case this is what you meant.